# TensorflowJS backend CPU kernel undefined is already registered

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am loading the TensorFlowJS library and backend GPU with these script tags:

```
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-core@2.1.0/dist/tf-core.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter@2.1.0/dist/tf-converter.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl@2.1.0/dist/tf-backend-webgl.js"></script>
```

This works, but it gives me this warning in the console:

> Your application contains ops that are small enough to be executed on the CPU backend, however the CPU backend cannot be found. Consider importing the CPU backend (@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu) for better performance.

BUT when I load the backend CPU with this tag:

```
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu"></script>
```

I get these errors:

```
kernel_registry.ts:142 The kernel 'undefined' for backend 'cpu' is already registered
```

And

```
backend.ts:665 Uncaught (in promise) Error: 'realDivide' not yet implemented or not found in the registry. 
Did you forget to import the kernel?
    at notYetImplemented (backend.ts:665)
```

If I load **both GPU and CPU**, I only get the `kernel undefined is already registered` warning.

Some other posts here on SO and GitHub say that some libraries are probably loaded twice? But I can't leave out any of these script tags...

Comment: I don't think that you need to load `tf-converter.js`

Comment: I think it's a bug in tensorflow. No matter what combination I try, there's always something loaded twice or not loaded at all. It also happens with the ML5.JS library, which simplifies the loading of tensorflow.